# load JS after changing the attribute value from dropdown on product add or product edit page backend

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, backend, magento-product-attributes

We are having brand and model two dropdown attributes on product level. We want to call JS when we change the value of brand while creating new product or editing existing product on backend.